# What do comments with [...] mean?

Tags: posts, comments, spam, akismet

I get a bunch of comments that simply repeat the title with '[...]'.
ie:

```
[...] Some cool post title [...]
```

Is this spam or is wordpress doing something wrong? I have the akismet plugin enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Its most likely to be a TrackBack or pingback:

> In a nutshell, TrackBack was designed
>   to provide a method of notification
>   between websites: it is a method of
>   person A saying to person B, "This is
>   something you may be interested in."
>   To do that, person A sends a TrackBack
>   ping to person B.